# How is the surface of a Bloch sphere a Hilbert space?

Tags: qiskit, bloch-sphere, hilbert-space

In the [linear algebra section](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-appendix/linear_algebra.html) of the Qiskit textbook appears the following claim regarding the Bloch sphere:

> The surface of this sphere, along with the inner product between qubit
> state vectors, is a valid Hilbert space.

It is pretty clear that by scaling any quantum statevector we can easily get a vector that points outside or inside the surface of the sphere.. I.e the surface of the sphere isn't a vector space.

From where is this contradiction coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The surface of a Bloch sphere is *not* a Hilbert space.

Maybe they meant to write that it's a valid *projective* Hilbert space (in particular it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^1$)? It's not a vector space, so it cannot be a Hilbert space (note that a "[projective Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space)" is, perhaps somewhat confusingly, *not* a Hilbert space).

Comment: Really interesting! So what is the right way to describe the Hilbert space that single qubit states live in?

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar the smallest Hilbert space containing all qubits is $\mathbb{C}^2$. The point is if you want a space where the elements are in bijection (1-to-1) with qubits, then that space is not the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$, but rather the *projective* space $\mathbb{CP}^1$, which as glS points out, is not a Hilbert space. I don't think one is more right than the other.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I look at it in the opposite direction, is it correct to say that in addition to qubits, $\mathbb{C}^2$ also includes vectors that are not normalized and/or contain global phases?

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar the projective space $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is what you get from $\mathbb{C}^2$ modulo an equivalence relation. In other words, if you take $\mathbb{C}^2$, and identify all points which only differ by a global phase and a normalisation factor (and define a suitable topology), you get $\mathbb{CP}^1$. So in this sense, yes, $\mathbb C^2$ includes vectors that are not normalizes and "contain global phases" (the latter does'nt actually mean much; you should say that it contains different vectors differering by a global phase, which all correspond to the same physical state)

Comment: Got it, makes sense, thank you for taking the time everyone for the clear explanations! I gave quick shout to the qiskit folks pointing them to this thread. They may already know this point and decided to "simplify" things when teaching it, but either way, I though it wouldn't hurt to let them know :)